# Highcharts not showing series data with javascript function

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have a .js code for the highcharts:

```
$(function loadTransactionsLevel() {
    //Auto call function, for 1 minute
    setInterval(loadTransactionsLevel, 60000);

    var nowDate = new Date();
    var nowYear = nowDate.getFullYear();
    var nowMonth = (nowDate.getMonth()+1);
    var nowDay = nowDate.getDate();
    var nowHour = nowDate.getHours();
    var nowMinus10Minutes = (nowDate.getMinutes() - 10);
    var nowMinutes = (nowDate.getMinutes() - 1 );

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            loading: 'Cargando...',
            months: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            weekdays: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
            shortMonths: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            exportButtonTitle: "Exportar",
            printButtonTitle: "Importar",
            rangeSelectorFrom: "Desde",
            rangeSelectorTo: "Hasta",
            rangeSelectorZoom: "Período",
            downloadPNG: 'Descargar imagen PNG',
            downloadJPEG: 'Descargar imagen JPEG',
            downloadPDF: 'Descargar imagen PDF',
            downloadSVG: 'Descargar imagen SVG',
            printChart: 'Imprimir',
            resetZoom: 'Reiniciar zoom',
            resetZoomTitle: 'Reiniciar zoom',
            thousandsSep: ",",
            decimalPoint: '.'
        }
    });


    $('#liveTransactionsLevel').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor: '#333333'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Traffic Level3',
            style: {
                color: '#dedede'
            }
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Messages passed',
            style: {
                color: '#dedede'
            }
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%A %d de %B de %Y', (new Date(nowYear + '-' + nowMonth + '-' + nowDay)), false) + ': ' +
                    '<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + '</b>';
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            },

            series: {
                animation: false
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A %d de %B de %Y', (new Date(nowYear + '-' + nowMonth + '-' + nowDay)), false),
                style: {
                    color: '#AAAAAA'
                }
            },

            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#dedede'
                }
            },

            type: 'datetime',
            min: Date.parse(nowYear + "-" + nowMonth + "-" + nowDay + " " + nowHour + ":" + nowMinus10Minutes + " UTC"),//Date.UTC(nowYear, nowMonth, nowDay, nowHour, nowMinus10Minutes),
            max: Date.parse(nowYear + "-" + nowMonth + "-" + nowDay + " " + nowHour + ":" + nowMinutes + " UTC"),//Date.UTC(nowYear, nowMonth, nowDay, nowHour, nowMinutes),
            showEmpty: true,
            tickInterval: 1000 * 60, // one minute
            tickPixelInterval: 10
        },


    yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Success',
                style: {
                    color: '#dedede'
                }
            },

            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#dedede'
                }
            },

            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            max: null,
            showEmpty: true
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            color: '#5DC05D',
            lineWidth: 2,
            name: 'Messages passed',
            data: getData()
        }]
    });
});


function getData() {

    var array_keys = [];
    var array_values = [];
    var data = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/flkLive/ws/root/success",
        data: "",
        success: function(values){

            for (var key in values) {
                if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                    array_keys.push(key);
                    array_values.push(values[key]);
                }
            }

            array_keys.sort();
            array_values.sort();

            for (var i = 0; i < array_keys.length; i++){

                data[i] = [
                    [ Date.parse(array_keys[i] + " UTC"), array_values[i] ]
                ]
            }

            alert(data);
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

But when I run the project, highcharts isn't showing any data, what's wrong?

Below is an image with the values to show in format (time_in_milliseconds, int_value):

[image]

Comment: Nothing to do with Java.

Comment: mmmmm wel... well...

Comment: You should have numbers for your yValue, not strings. Try to use parseFloat(array_values[i]) http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that at the point when the getData is invoked by your chart the data is empty, and that is what is returned to the chart ... actually not even that because you don't have a return statement in your function so my guess is that it will return undefined.

The ajax call to get your data is sent though but async, so on the success function, even if you return the data, that data will go nowhere.

What you need to do is either create the chart in the ajax callback, or use such a declaration to put the data in your chart and refresh it:

```
chart.series[0].setData(data,true);
```

chart in this case must be your chart store in a variable like this:

```
var chart = $('#liveTransactionsLevel').highcharts({
... })
```

You also need to add a return staement to your getData fucntion in order to avoid the chart initialization crashing with 'undefined' something.
In order to do this you need to move this right before you end the getData() function:

```
return data;
```

In this way, you'll have an empty chart, that will get populated when the ajax call finishes getting the data.

Comment: I dont understand, where set up chart.series[0].setData(data,true);
in mi .js file...

Comment: Instead of : alert(data); When the ajax call information has been added into the data array,

Comment: chart.series[0].setData(data,true);

            return data;
        }....

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? Can you provide a sample on how the data looks like?

Comment: No errores, data look like the picture attached in main post :)

Comment: can you see the picture?

Comment: yes, I see it, but it looks like your code expects a JSON format and what you showed my is juts a coma separated string so I am not sure how to handle that. Better setup a static in a JSFiddle and then I can help you with the debug.

Comment: Maybe series data expects a JSON format not sure... But how do this?

Comment: I add var data = getData();